# In Java is it possible to call a sibling class's protected method where the sibling has different type parameters?

Tags: generics, protected, siblings

Given the following parent class:

```
public class AbstractParent<T> {
    abstract protected void doSomething();
}
```

and the following child class:

```
public class DelegatingChildClass<T,U> extends AbstractParent<T> {
   AbstractParent<U> delegate;
   public DelegatingChildClass(AbstractParent<U> delegate) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   protected void doSomething() {
      delegate.doSomething();//<--- Problem line
   }
}
```

My understanding of protected methods is that access is limited to:

- classes in the same package as the declaring class
- classes that extend the declaring class

Since DelegatingChildClass extends AbstractParent, my expectation is that the delegate's doSomething() method would be accessible.  However the compiler complains about it having protected access.  Is this a compiler bug?  Or do I have a faulty understanding of how the protected access modifier is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"classes that extend the declaring class" means that you have access to the methods in the super class for the same object (`this`) along the hierarchy of extensions for this object. An object of type `DelegatingChildClass<T,U>` is also an Object of type `AbstractParent<T>`, so in the code for `DelegatingChildClass<T,U>` you can use the methods of `AbstractParent<T>` for the same object. This would allow `super.doSomething()`, but it does not make sense here because `super.doSomething()` is `abstract`.

With `delegate` it is not possible here to call `doSomething()`, because an object of type `DelegatingChildClass<T,U>` does not extend the object in variable `delegate` here. This kind of usage is called composition, not extension.

Comment: It sounds you're saying that an instance of a sub-class can only access protected methods declared in the parent when they're invoked on the current instance.  If this is what you're saying, then you're mistaken.

Comment: Apparently I'm mistaken.  I was thinking of access of private methods and variables from other instances, but that all within the same declaring class.  The relevant part of the JLS reads as follows:
* A protected member/constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.  (ie. only within the same child class)

For some reason when I asked the question, I couldn't find the correct portion of the language spec.  I've accepted your answer.